# Current through an electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

Is the current that flows through an electromagnet (after a long time has passed) simply given by Ohm’s law (V=IR). In which V would be the voltage of the battery that the solenoid is connected to, and R is the resistance of the wire that the solenoid is made of?

Note:[image]

The circuit looks like this.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct; the steady-state answer is just given by ohm's law.